# Jenkins pipeline to call SonarQube code coverage for node.js project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to do code coverage for node js project via Jenkins, I’ve one doubt that where to add the “sonar-project.properties” file, it in root repository that means in sonar-scanner installed repository or in the jenkins path i.e. “/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/”,

can some help to fix this I’m getting error while executing the pipeline.

Error log as follows:

/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/sonardemo/bin/sonar-scanner /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demosonar@tmp/durable-f32cf5e2/script.sh: 1: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/sonardemo/bin/sonar-scanner: not found [Pipeline] } WARN: Unable to locate ‘report-task.txt’ in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?

Comment: Did you run your unit tests w/coverage analyzer first? What's your invocation and youe scanner invocation?

Comment: I am trying to check code quality to perform automatic reviews with static analysis of code to detect bugs